# How to write schema for a Json element in KendoUI?

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

Help me how to write the schema for the following json object

```
{
    sev: [{
        t: "t1",
        v: v1
    }, {
        t: "t2",
        v: v2
    }],
    sum: [{
        te: "te1",
        ve: ve1
    }, {
        te: "te2",
        ve: ve2
    }, {
        te: "te3",
        ve: ve13
    }]
}
```

where `t`, `te` are strings and `v`, `ve` are numbers(integers).

If schema was written as following

```
      schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    s: { type: "string" },
                    t: { type: "number" },
                    g: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
```

For

```
{ s: "a", t: b, g: "c" }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if the first JSON object represents one data item **(see 1)** in the data, or the whole data with two items (`sev` and `sum`) **(see 2)**. In either case, the Kendo UI DataSource does not support such data structures and here is why:

1. Nested fields can be defined in the schema via [`from`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define), but only if they are **not** part of a nested array.
2. All data items must be plain JavaScript objects that are members of a single array. In this case, there are two arrays associated with two fields (`sev` and `sum`).

Here is an example with both options demonstrated.

http://dojo.telerik.com/AFiTE